# Quarto html display of a raw output table with the knitr engine

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, quarto

I'm trying to obtain the same HTML display from Quatro when writing a table
the usual way and as raw output.

The issue is that the raw output is missing the striped rows.

As a workaround, I surrounded the code block with an explicit cell `::: {.cell} ... :::`.

Here is a simple example to illustrate my point.

test.qmd

````
---
tbl-colwidths: [75,25]
format: html
---

```{r}
df <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=1:3)
```

1. Usual way of displaying a table

```{r}
knitr::kable(df)
```

2. Raw output (no stripes as the html table misses the `table-striped` class)

```{r}
#| results: asis
print(knitr::kable(df))
```

3. Surrouneded by `{.cell}` block

::: {.cell}
```{r}
#| results: asis
print(knitr::kable(df))
```
:::
````

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot] of the rendered page (`quarto render test.qmd`)

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what results you are wanting? Your code renders 3 same looking Kable tables, and not Sure what is wrong.

Comment: I updated my post with a picture. Notice the look of the second table as compared to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You could create separate (styles.css) `css` file where you can specify the background color of your tables using this code:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
```

Then you can say `css: styles.css` for your `html` format like this:

```
---
tbl-colwidths: [75,25]
format: 
  html:
       css: styles.css
---

{r}
df <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=1:3)

{r}
#| results: asis
print(knitr::kable(df))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works indeed but the issue with this solution is that you have to adapt the color in the styles.css to the html theme. I was hoping for some kind of buried execution options.